# Ruby on rails new object properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i need to add to my user new objet some new properties that i will define when the form is submited by retrieve them from my database, but when i submited the new properties are nill and i dont know why

```
def create
  plan        =   params[:user][:plan]
  @plan_vars  =   Plan.find(plan)

    @user        = User.new(user_params, :plan_id => @plan_vars.id, :lessons => @plan_vars.lessons)
    if @user.save
        flash[:success] = "Usuario creado exitosamente"
      redirect_to   users_path
  else
        flash[:warning] =   "Ooops... algo ha fallado :O #{@user.errors}"
        redirect_to  new_user_path
    end
  end
```

here is the user params

```
def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :phone, :document, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is what to do?**

Do this:

```
@user = User.new(user_params)
@user.plan_id = @plan_vars.id
@user.lessons = @plan_vars.lessons
@user.save
```

if nested form is used or @plan_vars returns array there results another type of error

Comment: Ok then accept answer. Encouragement keeps me helping in future too.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge plan params to `user_params` hash

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :phone, :document, :password,
                               :password_confirmation)
                       .merge(plan_id: @plan_vars.id, lessons: @plan_vars.lessons)
end


def create
  plan = params[:user][:plan]
  @plan_vars = Plan.find(plan)
  @user = User.new(user_params)
end
```

Hope, that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer something similar to @Lavika's answer, but with merge on create action

```
def create
  plan = params[:user][:plan]
  @plan_vars = Plan.find(plan)
  @user = User.new(user_params.merge(plan_id: @plan_vars.id, lessons: @plan_vars.lessons))
  # ...
end
```

@pradeep sapkota's answer is also a good option